# How to append a new value to a list in a dictionary and write it to JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm very new to python and I'm still trying to learn dictionaries. I made a dictionary of lists but I'm trying to append a value that I added to an existing list within the dictionary. However when I try to append that new value to that list, it doesn't write to the JSON file, it just keeps the file as it is.

I have this code

```
with open('students.json') as j:
    students = json.load(j)
for i in students:
    #print "entered here4"
    if(name == i):
            print "entered here5"
            for k in students[i]:
                print "entered here6"
                print k
                if(classes == k):
                    print "classes exists Success"
                     sys.exit()
                else:
                        students[i].append(classes)
                                #x = students[i].append(classes) 
                                #with open ('students.json', 'w') as f:
                                    #json.dump(x,f)
                                #this didn't work for me, it wrote "null" to my JSON file
                                print "user added"
                                sys.exit()
```

(Ignore the print statements, they were just for when I was trying to debug)

Currently my JSON file looks like this with only one student and his class

```
 {"student1": ["math"]}
```

I eventually want my dictionary to look like this

```
{'student1': ["math", "biology"], "student2": ["chemistry"], "student3": ["History", "biology", "physics"]}
```

How do I append new values to an existing list and how do I add new keys with its corresponding lists?

Comment: side note: if you are new to python i strongly suggest you learn python 3 and not python 2.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
  Both of your coding requests are covered quite well in many tutorials on line.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are updating the local variable but not writing the updates to the file.
What you need is to dump the final dictionary.

```py
with open("students.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(students, jsonFile)
```